# In Swing, how to automatically load the results to a frame after computation？

Tags: java, swing, jframe, textarea, outputstream

I am learning to build a GUI. Now I have a button. After I click the button, the program run some computation. I want to redirect the output and add it to the frame I create. How ever, I found out it only updates when I re-size the frame but not automatically. Would anyone point it to me how to do it automatically.

part of the code is

```
jbtnAlpha.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    Runnable runnable = new SVMthread(fnm_train,fnm_test,fnm_result,jfrm);
            Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
            t.start();
}   
    });
```

SVMthread is defined here

```
public class SVMthread implements Runnable{
    private String fnm_train;
    private String fnm_test;
    private String fnm_result;
    private JFrame jfrm;
    SVMthread(String fnm_train,String fnm_test,String fnm_result,JFrame jfrm){
        this.fnm_train=fnm_train;
        this.fnm_test=fnm_test;
        this.fnm_result=fnm_result;
        this.jfrm=jfrm;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
         jfrm.add(new ResultPanel());
         LibSVMTest.SVMrun(fnm_train,fnm_test,fnm_result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
 }
```

The ResultPanel is where I redirect the output

```
public class ResultPanel extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 30);
    private TextAreaOutputStream taOutputStream = new TextAreaOutputStream(
             textArea, "Test");

public  ResultPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER));
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(taOutputStream));
}

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to use only :

```
frame.revalidate();
```

Comment: please to remove SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame); and frame.invalidate();

Comment: -1 for updateComponentTreeUI(). That method is used for LAF changes by the System. All you need is revalidate() and repaint on the panel that you add components to on a visible GUI.

Answer (score 2):

1. Never make most Swing calls in a background thread like you're doing. That's grabbing a tiger by its tail -- it will turn around and bite you.
2. After adding or removing a component from a Swing container, call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container to get it to re-layout its components and repaint them.

---

**Edit**
Regarding your comment:

> I am new to this. Would you explain more what do you mean by background? Sorry if it is a dumb question.

Google: Concurrency in Swing. It will answer your questions.

Comment: Hi, I am new to this. Would you explain more what do you mean by background? Sorry if it is a dumb question.

Comment: @Liu: see edit. you've accepted an answer that does not address your threading issues. Not good.

Comment: Thanks. But I think the answer above it works for me right now. Maybe my comments made it a little confusing. I will delete my comments. However, I appreciate that you point out the problems.